Survival curves cross on survival analysis with time-dependent predictor variable
I'm running an extended Cox proportional hazard model for a time-dependent predictor variable. Basically I'm interested in learning if there were any changes to the duration of sickness absence episodes before and after legal reform X and legal reform Y.
My time-dependent variable is thus "era", with era=0 for before both legal reform X and legal reform Y, era=1 for after legal reform X but before legal reform Y and era=2 for the time period after both legal reforms X and Y. My dependent variable is sickness absence episode length in days.
I have run the multivariate model incorporating all control variables (all were statistically significant in bivariate models, the database is large, in the millions of observations). Everything looks good.
However, the survival curve looks as if it crosses at a certain point (specifically, the curves for era 1 and era 2). Does that violate the assumption of proportionality and thus invallidate all of my results for the extended Cox model?

You can see the survival curve here too: https://imgur.com/a/XNa2U8G
Thank you very much!

I only see two lines, and I don't see a crossing.  I know I'm nearsighted but ....

It looks less like crossing and more like Eras 1 and 2 are indistinguishable. What are the hazard ratios for the eras? You may want to make Era 2 the reference so you get the HR of Era 1 v Era 2.
